# Insert new column with value in CSV file, based on value from a column already there

Tags: csv, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to read a value from an object in a CSV File (Using PowerShell 3.0). Based on what that value is, I will create a new column and insert a value (in the same row).

For example, I have the CSV file:

```
Attribute1,Attribute2
Valuea1,Valueb1
Valueb1,Valuea1
Valuea1,Valueb1
Valueb2,Valuea2
Valuea2,Valueb2
```

For each "Valueb1" in `Attribute2` insert a value "Found" into a new column `Data`. So in the end, it should look like this (notice just the added `,` if there is no "Found"):

```
Attribute1,Attribute2,Data
Valuea1,Valueb1,Found
Valueb1,Valuea1,
Valuea1,Valueb1,Found
Valueb2,Valuea2,
Valuea2,Valueb2,
```

I'm not familiar with how nested loops work with objects in CSV files using PowerShell.

Comment: You don't need nested loops for this? What have you tried so far? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) with a value depending on the value of `Attribute2`:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *,
    @{n='Data';e={if ($_.Attribute2 -eq 'Valueb1') {'Found'} else {''}}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!!! I only had to make one small change `else {''}` to `else {$null}`. Thank you so much...